# Enumerate printers on a remote machine using EnumPrinters function

Tags: c++, winapi

So what I'm trying to do is to simply enumerate printers on a remote machine in my private network.
To do that I'm using EnumPrinters this way:

```
int main()
{
    DWORD const BUFFER_SIZE = 50;
    PRINTER_INFO_2* prninfo = NULL;
    DWORD RequestedBufferSize = 0;
    DWORD InfoLevel = 0;
    bool suc = EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL|PRINTER_ENUM_NAME,"\\10.0.0.3",2,NULL,0,&RequestedBufferSize,&InfoLevel);
    int err = GetLastError();
    return 0;
}
```

In the end err = 16385 which is an error code I found no document about.

I will only mention that when I told the function to return info about the local printers it worked.

Does someone has a clue what's wrong here?

Comment: Sure you don't need `"\\\\YOTAM-PC"` or `"\\\\10.0.0.3"`?

Comment: By the way, there's nothing in the docs saying to call `GetLastError` if it fails, so there's no use in checking the error code. One comment does mention something about `SetLastError(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)` being called if you pass an insufficient buffer into it, though.

Comment: It also looks like you're not passing in `prninfo` when the corresponding parameter is `out`, not `out_opt`.